# Graph representation

Tags: graph-theory

In the famous paper „Contraction Hierarchies: Faster and Simpler Hierarchical Routing in Road Networks“ where contraction hierarchies were first introduced the authors talk about a Graph G´ with V´= v…n  in section 2: „Contraction“. Then later in that section they refer to a node u ∈ v + 1..n . What do they mean with v + 1…n , what kind of set ist that? Why do they use a sum?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I can't find the definition you mentionned. Can you precise the page number?

Comment: http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/contract.pdf page 3 or 321 depending on how you look at it

Comment: I never saw this notation and reading the introduction of the paper did not helped me at all. However, I found the thesis of the author that has the same title, maybe it will help you to figure it out? https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=453e6c598a903e479074d3b2c17610446749a9d7